# Vue Comonpent test using cypress, getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, cypress, pinia

Here are my code snippets:

`Test.vue`

```
<template>
  <button v-show="store.common == 'hi'" @click="func">
    hello world
  </button>
</template>

<script setup>
import {mainStore} from './index.js'
import {check} from './check.js'

function func() {
  check();
}

</script>
```

`check.js`

```
import {mainStore} from './index.js'

// need define this store here in project.
let store = mainStore();

function check() {
// store may be updated, for example from backend.
  store.common = 'hello';
}

export {check};
```

`index.js`

```
import {defineStore} from "pinia"

export const mainStore = defineStore('main', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      common: 'hi', 
    }
  },
  getters: {}, 
  actions: {}, 
})
```

My test file, `temp.cy.js`

```
import {mount} from 'cypress/vue'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import Test from './Test.vue'
import {createPinia, setActivePinia} from "pinia"

describe('for example', () => {
  const app = createApp({});
  beforeEach(() => {
    const pinia = createPinia();
    app.use(pinia);
    setActivePinia(pinia);
  });
  
  it('render', () => {
    mount(Test);
  });
})
```

When I ran this test, I'll get a error: `getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia.`

I tried to change code of `check.js` to this:

```
import {mainStore} from './index.js'

// need define this store here in project.
let store = null;

function getStore() {
  if (store === null) {
    store = mainStore();
  }
}

function check() {
  getStore();
  store.common = 'hello';
}

export {check};
```

or

```
import {mainStore} from './index.js'
import {onBeforeMount} from 'vue'

// need define this store here in project.
let store = null;

onBeforeMount(() => {
  store = mainStore();
});

function check() {
  store.common = 'hello';
}

export {check};
```

and then component cannot be rendered, get error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading common)`
How can I fix this problem? what's wrong with my code?

Comment: check.js is a mistake, you aren't supposed to be use a store like that. mainStore() function exists to access a store at the moment when you need it, not at the top of a module. check() function likely should be store action, this is the logic that belongs to a store

Comment: In check.js, many functions use a same store. If i don't use mainStore() at the top of a module, the Test.vue can't be rendered.

Comment: You could revise the way you write store logic. What you do is not conventional and results in poor testability besides other problems. Usually you write all code that belongs to store inside a store. Even if you need to do this outside, you do `mainStore().common = 'hello'`, this is why pinia stores are functions and not ready to use stores. As for the rest, it seems what the answer describes

Answer (score 3):

In the test there is no connection between the `app` you created that uses Pinia and the Test component you are mounting, hence the error.

Try creating a custom mount command as per the example [Replicating Plugins](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/vue/examples#Replicating-Plugins)

```js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia' // or Vuex
import { mount } from 'cypress/vue'
import { h } from 'vue'

Cypress.Commands.add('mount', (component, ...args) => {
  args.global = args.global || {}
  args.global.plugins = args.global.plugins || []
  args.global.plugins.push(createPinia())

  return mount(() => {
    return h(VApp, {}, component)
  }, ...args)
})

describe('for example', () => {
  it('render', () => {
    mount(Test);
  });
})
```